# Why I cannot store abstract class in map by const reference?

Tags: c++

I have some base abstract class A like that:

```
class A
{
  public:
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

I want to use following map:

```
 std::map<std::string, const A&> some_map;
```

But compiler tells that Code declares an instance of an abstract class or structure. It seems for me weird

EDIT: following type works fine:

```
std::map<std::string, const A*> some_map;
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: Neither clang nor gcc forbid me from creating `map<T, U&>` and using it (except for the obviously impossible code like default-initialized references or reassigning them)

Comment: The code compiles fine using g++6. What compiler did you use?

Comment: @Donghui Zhang, i am using msvc2015 studio with its compiler

Comment: @krzaq You can't do it anyways, it's not legal.

Comment: Well, it seems to be Visual Studio specific then. I guess if you continue to use Visual Studio, you'll have to use a workaround such as storing a pointer instead of a reference.

Comment: @DonghuiZhang Just because gcc does not give you a diagnostic does not mean the code is correct. It is not, independent of the compiler in use.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I didn't see anything to this effect in container requirements. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: @krzaq See the dupe.

Comment: @BaummitAugen thanks, it's clear now :)